# Eclipse Luna update to 4.4.1 fails in Ubuntu 14 (32-bit)

Tags: 14.04, updates, eclipse

With Luna running, I select the Help:Check for Updates option and am shown a list of updates, which are all checked *except* the one for Luna 4.4.1.

I hit "Select All" and try to update. It fails with this message:

```
An error occurred while uninstalling
session context was:(profile=epp.package.standard, phase=org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.engine.phases.Uninstall, operand=[R]org.eclipse.platform_root 4.4.0.v20140606-1558 --> null, action=org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.touchpoint.natives.actions.CleanupzipAction).
Backup of file /opt/eclipse-luna/notice.html failed.
File that was copied to backup could not be deleted: /opt/eclipse-luna/notice.html
```

Comment: What exactly is "Luna"?  Eclipse, or an OS variant?

Comment: @ThomasW. I edited the question for OP: It's definitely eclipse based on the update process

Comment: @OP can you post the output of typing `file /opt/eclipse-luna/notice.html` into a console?

Comment: It's just one line of output: /opt/eclipse-luna/notice.html: XML document text

Comment: Here are the first lines of the file:  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1" ?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/x
html1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1" />
<title>Eclipse Foundation Software User Agreement</title>
</head>

<body lang="EN-US">
<h2>Eclipse Foundation Software User Agreement</h2>
<p>April 9, 2014</p>

<h3>Usage Of Content</h3>

<p>THE ECLIPSE FOUNDATION MAKES AVAILABLE SOFTWARE,

Comment: I tried renaming the offending file, adding a ".bak" extension. Now Eclipse's Available Updates window shows only the 4.4.1 package, but includes the message "Insufficient access privileges to apply this update". I have never tinkered with any access privileges, and I have a "plain vanilla" installation of Ubuntu. Surely I'm not the only person to have this issue?

Answer (score 2):

Discovered the trick: run Eclipse (just this **once**, just for updating) as root.

In Terminal, run

```
gksudo /opt/eclipse-luna/eclipse
```

or whatever the path is on your system.

Then proceed with the update. 
This worked updating Luna from 4.4.0 to 4.4.1

Never ran into this when using Eclipse on a Mac.

Comment: If installed in `/home` then `sudo` won't be needed, but since it's in `/opt` you will need it.